# Populate "SIgn Here" tab with infromation from "Text" tab

Tags: docusignapi

I have 2 fields in my document.
The first field has Type - Text "Enter your full name", it is supposed to be filled in by the user, I want to set an image of Sign Here tab (see image below) based on the value from this text field.

For example, if one user will enter the field "Enter your full name" - "Eddie Peppa", when he will go to next field and click on Sign Here, signature(proposal) will be created with "Eddie Peppa". (Right now it goes from signer name, and I can't change it.). Also please tell me how to change automatic guide order, to ask first to enter Name and then Signature. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the name of the signer before you start a signing session, I encourage you to use PowerForms. The approach you're trying to take (asking the user for their name inside the envelope) is problematic from a legal aspect as it's unclear who the signer is when DocuSign initiates the signing ceremony. 
PowerForms enables you to create a URL where users first fill their name and then you show them the signing UI. You can do that in your app of course, but for some reason you decided not to ask the user's name before you generate the signing session.

Comment: Thanks, understood. Maybe it's possible to open Sign Here in "Draw" section (instead of Select style)...so user will see that signature is empty and will just draw new one?